# Interface A incorrectly extends interface B

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given this interface:

```
interface Props extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  compLevel: string;
  property: Property;
  comps: Property[];
}
```

I'm having difficulties with the `property` attribute given that it already exists on `HTMLAttributes` as `property?: string;`:

> Interface 'Props' incorrectly extends interface
>   'HTMLAttributes'.   Types of property 'property' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type 'SerializedObject' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Renaming the attribute works though I'd rather not do that.What is a recommended interface to extend/approach to use so that I don't need to redefine `className` on my `Props`?

Answer (score 7):

What are you going to do with `Props`?  You probably shouldn't use it in places that expect a `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>`.  As stated, and treating the code as a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example, I'd probably define `Props` like this:

```
// SimpleSpread<L, R> is a simplified version of what happens when you
// do an object spread like {...left, ...right} where left is of type L and
// right is of type R.  It is the type R, with any properties on L that
// don't exist in R.  (It doesn't work if a key in L is an optional property in
// R, which is why this is simplified)
type SimpleSpread<L, R> = R & Pick<L, Exclude<keyof L, keyof R>>;

// Define the props you want to spread into React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
interface PropsExtra {
  compLevel: string;
  property: Property;
  comps: Property[];
}

// Define Props
interface Props
  extends SimpleSpread<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, PropsExtra> {}
```

This works by treating `Props` like `PropsExtra` with only those properties from `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>` that *do not appear* in `PropsExtra`.  So this will end up *overwriting* the `property` property instead of *extending* it.

That will now have no error.

---

Do note that the following will be an error:

```
declare function acceptAttributes(attrs: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>);
declare const p: Props;
acceptAttributes(p); // error! p is not a React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
```

Because they differ in the types of the `property` property (heh), a value of type `Props` is no longer a valid `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>` value.  Anything which expects the latter will not accept the former.  You could then change the expected argument type of such functions, which will likely cascade outwards until this change touches more of your code base than you intended.

So it really depends on your use case if this will work for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since the attribute of 'property' already exists on HTMLAttribute, I can see three ways to move forward:

1. Rename the property to another more precise term that does not overlap with the already existing attribute (e.g. propsProperty)
2. If the values are somehow similar, the property could be transformed into a SerializedObject to match the type signature
3. Rename the property to _property, and set the getter and setter of the interface to alter from _property instead of property. (Haven't tested this one yet)